# Mostrar y ocultar un EditText por medio de un Spinner

Tags: android, edittext, spinner

Intento hacer que por medio de un Spinner, al seleccionar la opcion de "PERSONA NATURAL" no aparezcan algunos EditText y al seleccionar la otra opcion muestre esos campos y oculte otros.

```
String [] tpersona = {"PERSONA NATURAL","PERSONA JURIDICA"};
ArrayAdapter <String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.spinner_item_banco,tpersona);
spinner_persona.setAdapter(adapter);

public void Persona(View view){
String seleccion = spinner_persona.getSelectedItem().toString();
if(seleccion.equals("PERSONA JURIDICA")){
IngreseRuc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una forma es usar el método `setOnItemSelectedListener` de acuerdo a la posición del item
del spinner:

```
 spinner_persona.setAdapter(adapter);

 spinner_persona.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if (position == 1) {   //0 es para PERSONA NATURAL, 1 para PERSONA JURIDICA
                    ingreseRuc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    ingreseRuc.setVisibility(View.GONE);  // ó INVISIBLE
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                //  tu código
            }
        });
```